# Elementtree and counter - finding corresponding value

Tags: python

I have an element tree python code with counter.  I need to get the specific name (product name, Supplier name and supplier id) .
below code get me the product id for which highest quantity is sold. Now i need to get the product name, Supplier name and supplier id for corresponding product id

```
orders = root.findall("./orders")
total ={}
for order in orders:
    orderdetails = order.findall("./orderdetails")
    for detail in orderdetails:
        productid = detail.findall("./products/productid")[0].text
        quantity = detail.findall("./quantity")
        if productid in total.keys():
            total[productid]+=float(quantity[0].text)
        else:
            print productid,float(quantity[0].text)
            print total
            total[productid ]=float(quantity[0].text)


print Counter(total).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

---

Here is the XML

```
-<nwind>


-<orders another="Friday" orderid="10248">


-<customers>

<companyname>Vins et alcools Chevalier</companyname>

<customerid>VINET</customerid>

</customers>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>72</productid>

<productname>Mozzarella di Giovanni</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>34.8</unitprice>

<quantity>5</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>14</supplierid>

<companyname>Formaggi Fortini s.r.l.</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>11</productid>

<productname>Queso Cabrales</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>14</unitprice>

<quantity>12</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>5</supplierid>

<companyname>Cooperativa de Quesos 'Las Cabras'</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>42</productid>

<productname>Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>9.8</unitprice>

<quantity>10</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>20</supplierid>

<companyname>Leka Trading</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>

</orders>


-<orders orderid="10249">


-<customers>

<companyname>Toms Spezialitaten</companyname>

<customerid>TOMSP</customerid>

</customers>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>14</productid>

<productname>Tofus</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>18.6</unitprice>

<quantity>9</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>6</supplierid>

<companyname>Mayumi's</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>51</productid>

<productname>Manjimup Dried Apples</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>42.4</unitprice>

<quantity>40</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>24</supplierid>

<companyname>G'day, Mate</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>

</orders>


-<orders orderid="10250">


-<customers>

<companyname>Hanari Carnes</companyname>

<customerid>HANAR</customerid>

</customers>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>65</productid>

<productname>Louisiana Fiery Hot Pepper Sauce</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>16.8</unitprice>

<quantity>15</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>2</supplierid>

<companyname>New Orleans Cajun Delights</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>41</productid>

<productname>Jack's New England Clam Chowder</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>7.7</unitprice>

<quantity>10</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>19</supplierid>

<companyname>New England Seafood Cannery</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>51</productid>

<productname>Manjimup Dried Apples</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>42.4</unitprice>

<quantity>35</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>24</supplierid>

<companyname>G'day, Mate</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>

</orders>

</nwind>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import Counter,defaultdict

root = ET.ElementTree(file="nwind_medium.xml")

orders = root.findall("./orders")
total = {}
# intalize the default dict here
productdetails=defaultdict(list,{})
for order in orders:
    orderdetails = order.findall("./orderdetails")
    for detail in orderdetails:
        productid = detail.findall("./products/productid")[0].text
        quantity = detail.findall("./quantity")
        supplierid = detail.findall("./suppliers/supplierid")[0].text
        companyname = detail.findall("./suppliers/companyname")[0].text
        productname = detail.findall("./products/productname")[0].text
        #use append to add the details into the product details
        productdetails[productid].append((supplierid,companyname,productname))
        if productid in total.keys():
            total[productid]+=float(quantity[0].text)
        else:


            total[productid]=float(quantity[0].text)

maxprod= Counter(total).most_common(1)[0][0]
print set(productdetails[maxprod])
```

explanation:

1. since same product id has different product names,suppliersname,id to accomplish we need to intilize (learn here)[defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)
2. then suppling the product id to the product detail You get the details what You needed

Comment: @sundar... For some reason, the solution is giving me a different answer when running on a bigger XML file.  My original code that is posted works on both small and large XML file.  With the new solution with "defaultdic", I'm getting a wrong answer.  It's a bit weird because it's working find on the small XML file.  Please advise.  Thank you

Comment: @user_new_in_python is there some way where i can seee your large xml ?

Comment: It's a bit long XML file.  Can I email it to you?

Comment: @user_new_in_python no http://pastebin.com/ use this to store it and send me link

Comment: Please see link. http://pastebin.com/dgtk4ui8

Comment: correct productid should be 60 on the new XML file.

Comment: @user_new_in_python please make it public afterwards u can delete it. unable to get it

Comment: sorry about that.  It's public now.

Comment: Here's the new link. http://pastebin.com/w7qtnh6b  I cannot paste the whole thing because it exceeds the limit.  This is just 1/3 of the file.

Comment: @user_new_in_python what should be the answer i got ['14', 'Formaggi Fortini s.r.l.', 'Gorgonzola Telino'] its product id and total quantity '31': 458.0,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56425/discussion-between-sundar-nataraj--and-user-new-in-python).

Comment: I think I'm all good.  I just run a separate statement outside the loop to find the corresponding value.  Thanks again for your help.  Much appreciated.